# Working with simple equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all positive $n$ such that $\frac {4n - 1}{2n + 1}$ is an integer.

I let $\frac {4n - 1}{2n + 3} = m$ for some m in $\mathbb N$. Then $4n - 1 = 2mn + 3m.$ So, $-1 = 2mn + 3m - 4m.$ Multiplying both sides by $3$ and adding $-18$ gives $-21 = 6mn – 12n + 9m - 18 = (2n + 3)(3m - 6)$. Except $-21 = 6mn – 12n + 9m - 18$ doesn't hold for $m = n = 1.$ Before I can proceed I'd like my mistake pointed out to me.

edit: here's the fixed quote:

> Find all positive $n$ such that $\frac {4n - 1}{2n + 3}$ is a positive integer.

Comment: The fraction is a positive integer.

Comment: Why do you use $2n+1$ in the problem and then $2n+3$ in your work? $m=n=1$ certainly doesn't work for $2n+3$, even before you do any work

Comment: I quoted the problem wrong. The version in my work is the correct one.

Comment: If $m=n=1$ then $\frac{4n-1}{2n+3} = \frac{3}{5} \neq 1$ so I'm not sure what your question is

Comment: Oh, I see now. The question seems to have broken a certain rule here. Since I know the answer, I don't mind it being deleted for violating the rules :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: use that $$\frac{4n-1}{4n+1}=1-2\, \left( 4\,n+1 \right) ^{-1}$$

Comment: Actually, I am supposed to solve this problem in three different ways. The one I attempted in the OP is the method number two. Your hint is the third one. Here's a question I wanted to ask: $\frac {6n + 9}{3n - 8} = 2 + \frac{25}{3n - 8} \in \mathbb N$. I understand why this equality holds, but how do ou get the right  side if you only have the left one?

Comment: $$\frac{4n-1}{4n+1}=\frac{4n+1-2}{4n+1}=1-\frac{2}{4n+1}$$